# Do different ANT versions handle generics differently?

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors, javac

I did an assignment that has the following code in it

```
int status;
Object[] Data = new Object[3];
message.readArray(Data, 0, 3) //this is a call to an external library that reads some values (all integers) into 'Data'. 0 is the start and 3 is the count
status = (int) Data[2];
```

From searching, I found that the last line should be something like

```
status= ((Integer)Data[2]).intValue();
```

Now the problem is that the initial code compiled and run without issues using ANT, but my evaluator gets the error:

```
java:146: inconvertible types
[javac] found   : java.lang.Object
[javac] required: int
[javac]             status = (int) Data[2];
[javac]                            ^
```

I'm not sure what version of ANT and/or JAVA he is using, but mine is ANT 1.7.1 and JAVAC 1.7.0. Does anyone know why this seems to be a problem on their end and why it compiles on mine?

Comment: You and your evaluation might be using different JDK versions or compiling to different version levels.

Comment: Ant doesn't handle generics at all. Java does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the java version not the ANT version. Make sure he is using the same version of JAVAC as you.

Comment: Not gotten confirmation yet, but attempted compiling and setting target and source to 1.6 and I got those same errors (plus one on strings in 'switch' not being supported in 1.6). Thanks!